# .post javascript with PHP to enable select statement return

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

.post javascript with PHP to enable select statement return

Okay I got this script that is working

```
$.post('2.php', { id: 12345 }, function(data) {
    // Increment vote count, etc
});
```

This is what my 2.php looks like

```
$data = $_POST['id'];

$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
echo fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);
```

So I did a test, I run 1.php and saw test.txt was created with the data.

this prove the connection was successful.

Now is the difficult part.

I need to send id:12345 to 2.php, and 2.php need to

```
"select * from account where account_id='$data'";
```

And then the return result, I think of using MYSQL_ASSOC or MYSQL_BOTH 
I not sure which is best.

Then get the result, be it 1 row result or many row result.

Return as an array and then use 1.php to perform

```
alert( ArrayReturnResult );
```

Assuming that my account table have this value

```
account_id, account_name, account_phone, account_email
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you need help with? Connecting/querying the db, ie. `new PDO(...)/new mysqli(...)` and `->query("SELECT...")`; getting the results, ie. `while($row = fetch())...`; or sending the results back to `$.post()`, ie. `echo json(encode($results))`? Right now your question(s) is not clear, and my be too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you know how to establish a database connection (using PDO, of course), you could do something like this in 2.php:

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $data = (int) $_POST['id'];

  // query the table
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM account WHERE account_id = :id");
  $stmt->bindValue(":id", $data, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();

  // fetch results
  $buffer = array();
  while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $buffer[] = $row;
  }

  // output JSON string
  echo json_encode($buffer);
}
```

Of course, this isn't tested... and probably isn't secure if dealing with personal details.

Don't forget to update your `$.post` method so that it can expect JSON-encoded data:

```
$.post('2.php', { id: 12345 }, function(data) {
   console.log(data); // this will now be a JS object, from 2.php
}, 'json');
```